# Why did I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Newbie here, I'm trying to make a search filter and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

The problem looks like it's the data type of what is entered with toLowerCase, but I don't know exactly how to fix it.

I've tried everything in the answer below

```
let mangas = [
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Some Manga',
        author: 'Some Name',
        artist: 'Some Name',
        chapters: 'Some Number',
    },
```

```
function Search() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar1 />
            <NavbarExplore />
            <section className="bg-light" style={{ minHeight: 700 }}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="column pb-5 mb-5" style={{ minHeight: 800 }}>
                        <h1
                            className="top-header pt-5 mb-5"
                            style={{ borderBottom: '1px black solid', width: 400 }}
                        >
                            Full List
                        </h1>{' '}
                        <div className="nav-item px-2 mr-4 mb-4">
                            <form className="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
                                <input
                                    type="search"
                                    placeholder="Search.."
                                    className="mr-sm-2 pl-3 my-2 ml-3 search3"
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        setSearch(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
                            {Object.keys(mangas)
                                .filter((val) => {
                                    if (search === '') {
                                        return val;
                                    } else if (
                                        val.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                                    ) {
                                        return val;
                                    } else {
                                        return 'null';
                                    }
                                })
                                .map((key) => (
                                    <li key={key}>
                                        <div className="card m-2 mb-3 p-2 listbox">
                                            <div className="column">
                                                <div className="col-sm mb-2" style={{ color: 'black' }}>
                                                    <h3>{mangas[key].name}</h3>
```

Comment: At least one of `search` or `val.name` is `undefined`. You need to debug which one and figure out why.

Comment: Wait, you have `Object.keys(mangas) filter((val) => { /* ... */})`, that means `val` can only be a string. Did you mean `Object.values(mangas)`? Or maybe `mangas[key].name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())`?

Comment: Object.values doesn't work because I'm looking for the value inside of the key, I also tried mangas[key].name before, it took away the error, but it as a result, the sorting function didn't work. I appreciate the attempts!

Comment: If you just want the values of the array, then `mangas.filter()`? I am really not sure what is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: I want this to be a search filter, user enters words/letters, and filters out anything that is not included in what the user inputs. The input should take in the 'name' attribute from the array to find it. Also you are correct, val.name is probably the problem, just not sure how to fix it. The things I've tried are mangas.keys.name, mangas[keys].name, mangas.name, val.keys.name, etc

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
  Object.values(mangas).filter((val) => {

                                if (search === '') {
                                    return val;
                                } else if (                                    
    val?.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                                ) {
                                    return val;
                                } else {
                                    return 'null';
                                }
});
```

Comment: Try using Object.values instead of Object.keys

Comment: It can't find the attribute 'name'

Comment: It will return object

Comment: Even you don't need to use Object.keys and Object.values both .You can simply write mangas.filter .

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you explain a bit more

Comment: I mean if you want to iterate on array why you are using Object.keys and Object.values . Just use arrayName.filter

Comment: Above returns error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: try using like val?.name. I have edited the above answer for you